# LUDecomposition for non-square matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

How do we go about finding the `LUDecomposition` for non-square matrices. When i try to input the standard `LUDecomposition` command, it tells me that the matrix is not-invertible (understandable). Is there still a way to somehow find the `LUDecomposition`?

This is the matrix:

```
a = {{2, 4, -1, 5, -2}, {-4, -5, 3, -8, 1}, {2, -5, -4, 1, 8}, {-6, 0, 7, -3, 1}}
```

This is what i did:

```
{lu, p, c} = LUDecomposition[a]
```

Result:

> LUDecomposition::sing: "Matrix {{2,4,-1,5,-2},{-4,-5,3,-8,1},{2,-5,-4,1,8},{-6,0,7,-3,1}} is singular"
>
> {{2, 4, -1, 5, -2}, {-2, 3, 1, 2, -3}, {1, -3, 0, 2, 1}, {-3, 4, 0, 2,
>       5}}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, 0}

The output data is different from the input data so i figured i may be able to still go ahead and use the upper and lower triangularize commands, but i get an error saying that *Mathematica* can't combine objects of unequal length.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer is incomplete, but I don't know if I'll get time to finish it soon.)

`LUDecomposition` nominally requires its input matrix to be square, as per the documentation. As far as I can see, the output in this case is correct except in the last row:

```
{lu, a, b} = 
 LUDecomposition[{{2, 4, -1, 5, -2}, {-4, -5, 3, -8, 1},
                  {2, -5, -4, 1, 8}, {-6, 0, 7, -3, 1}}];

ReplacePart[
 LowerTriangularize[lu[[All, 1 ;; -2]]],
 {i_, i_} -> 1] . 
UpperTriangularize[lu] // MatrixForm
```

Outputs $\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 2 & 4 & -1 & 5 & -2 \\
 -4 & -5 & 3 & -8 & 1 \\
 2 & -5 & -4 & 1 & 8 \\
 -6 & 0 & 7 & -5 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

I'm not sure what the fix is.

Answer (score 1):

A **wasteful** method:

```
mat = {{2, 4, -1, 5, -2}, {-4, -5, 3, -8, 1},
       {2, -5, -4, 1, 8}, {-6, 0, 7, -3, 1}};
{m, n} = Dimensions[mat];
{lu, piv} = Most[LUDecomposition[mat]] // Quiet;
lm = Drop[LowerTriangularize[lu, -1], None, -1] + IdentityMatrix[m];
um = LinearSolve[lm, mat];
lm.um == IdentityMatrix[m][[piv]].mat
   True
```